# How to add <p> tag item to drop down list dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that will take user input and differentiate it with a coma `,`. Next, my table will also let user to add column. So how can I get all the user input from `existing group` and `add new group` and show it on the drop down list dynamically? For example: a user submit 2 group named `Nurse` and `Doctor`, and when user add a new column , the drop down list should consist of existing and new group values which are `IT, Cleaning, Accountant, Nurse, Doctor` . The dropdownlist should able to update the values dynamically from `existing` and `add new group` records.

**User input `Nurse` and `Doctor` to the `add new group` category:**

[image]

**User add column:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**
The dropdownlist should retrieve the values in realtime from `existing group` and `add new group` which are `IT, Cleaning, Accountant, Nurse, Doctor` . The reason why I prefer realtime is because user should able to choose the latest group that they added from the drop down list without refreshing the webpage.

[image]

Full Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="member_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

 <h1>Existing Group</h1>
      <p>IT, Cleaning, Accountant</p>
      <h1>Add New Group</h1>
      <p id="myP"></p>
      <input type="tel" id="group" name="group" placeholder="enter group name">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
   

<button onclick="javascript:appendColumn()">Add column</button>

<script>
function createSelectEl(values){
    var select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = "group1";
    select.id = "groupId"
    // 1st option
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = 'Select One';
    select.appendChild(option);
    for (const val of values)
    {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = val;
        option.text = val;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    return select;
}

let groupNum = 1;
const tableEl = document.getElementById('member_table');

// append column to the HTML table
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    const values = ["IT", "Cleaning", "Accountant", "Nurse", "Doctor" ];
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), createSelectEl(values), 'col');
    // createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}

// create DIV element and append to the table cell
function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // create DIV element
    //txt = document.createTextNode(text); // create text node
  // div.appendChild(txt); // append text node to the DIV
  div.appendChild(text);
  div.setAttribute('class', style); // set DIV class attribute
  div.setAttribute('className', style); // set DIV class attribute for IE (?!)
  cell.appendChild(div); // append DIV to the table cell
}
</script>
<script>
const submit = document.querySelector('button');
const input  = document.querySelector('input');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const myP    = document.querySelector('p#myP');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  const values = input.value.split(',');
  
  if (myP.innerText == '')
  {
    myP.innerText = values;
  }
  else
  {
    myP.innerText += ', ' + values;
  }
  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Separate your data and logic from the DOM and HTML. Store the groups and data separately and simply render the groups as either a comma-delimited list for the paragraph or as a list of `option`s for the `select`. That way you won't have to reparse things every time you add a group.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to create logic for this problem, Well you add new categories in myP which is your paragraph so when you create column and add dropdown I have fetch the values from p and split it with ',' and append it in your dropdown list

```
function appendColumn() {

  // open loop for each row and append cell
  for (let i = 0; i < tableEl.rows.length; i++) {
    const values = ["IT", "Cleaning", "Accountant"];
    const myP  = document.querySelector('p#myP');
    var categories = myP.innerText.split(',');
    for(let j =0; j < categories.length; j++){
    values.push(categories[j]);
    }
    createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), createSelectEl(values), 'col');
    // createCell(tableEl.rows[i].insertCell(tableEl.rows[i].cells.length), i, 'col');
  }

  tableEl.rows[0].querySelector('td:last-child').textContent = 'Group' + groupNum;
  groupNum++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is very close to my expectation. But i figure out that if u add a new group name , the previous drop down list column doesn't have the new added value, it only work if you add another new column

Comment: Yes, because drop down has already set the value we can change already rendered dropdowns or recreate them depends on your flow.